# No PCL option for Xamarin project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I'm just getting into Xamarin Forms based app development and most of the articles -- if not all -- that I've come across suggest I create a new Xamarin Forms project using Portable Class Library (PCL) approach.

I'm running the latest version of Visual Studio 2017 15.5.1 and when I start a new Xamarin Forms project, I get the following screen with no PCL option.

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have an example article? Is it relating to Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: Here's one coming directly from official Xamarin site: https://blog.xamarin.com/authenticate-mobile-apps-using-microsoft-authentication-library/ As per my question, it is related to VS 2017 because Xamarin tooling in VS 2017 may have been updated to reflect recent changes to Xamarin Forms app architecture.

Comment: To be fair that is an article from 2016, so maybe something's shifted or they've simplified the workflow. How would you know if you're using the correct option? Maybe PCL is implied now. I'd give it a shot and see what's missing before presuming the option you need isn't there.

Comment: That's exactly my point, hence the question here.

Comment: Use .NetStandard, it is the replacement for Profile-based PCL libraries.

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks for your response. Should I assume, going forward, Xamarin Forms do not support .NET Framework?

Comment: @Sam ? I do not understand that question.

Comment: @SushiHangover I guess Xamarin never supported the full .NET Framework. I'm coming from ASP.NET world where we have to choose between .NET Framework or .NET Core.

Comment: @Sam Xamarin has supported the Mono-based .Net framework on iOS/Android, so true in terms of Microsoft's .NET Framework and a one-to-one mapping. .NetStandard 2.0 is the way of the future in terms of the ability to access the *largest set* of ".Net Framework" features possible in a cross-platform agnostic way, but it does not have a one to one mapping to every API in .NET Framework (4.5/4.6/4.7+). i.e. The .Net APIs for Window's performance counters makes no sense on Linux/macOS/iOS/Android, but C# Sockets do and their implementation is truly different on each platform, but user's code is not.

Comment: @SushiHangover Thank you for your help. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. I'd like you to get credit for your help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You Can Select .Net Standard. it is Replacement of PCL.

NET Standard is a formal specification of .NET APIs that are intended to be available on all .NET runtimes (such as .NET Framework, Mono, and .NET Core)

For More Details Please visit : https://blog.xamarin.com/building-xamarin-forms-apps-net-standard/